# SQL Searching for String in DB with Special Character/s

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a search in the database with special characters, specifically string with apostrophe.

For example, I want to search for the string: "Sandy's dog", but I just entered "sandys dog" leaving out the apostrophe.  Even though "Sandy's dog" exists in the database, it doesn't seem to show it in the results.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT *  FROM `Table` WHERE `Title` LIKE '%sandys dog%'
```

I have searched everywhere and I can't seem to find a solution that works.

EDIT
Limitations: the string is user generated
Notes: 
- If a user searches for sandy's dog with the apostrophe, it works fine as expected.
- Ultimately I would like to get all possible results, if the table contains both strings with and without apostrophe.

Comment: Why not use parameterized queries and search for the actual value? You could do `SELECT *  FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE '%sandy%s dog%'` or `SELECT *  FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE '%sandy_s dog%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL server, you can use REPLACE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE REPLACE(Title, '''', '') LIKE '%sandys dog%'
```

The double-apostrophe inside the string is an escape character, so it finds any apostrophes in the string and replaces them with blank strings.

Comment: Then, Please mark this answer as correct @Ivy. As, it will help other user too to find this answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using escape sequences.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Something like, `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE '%sandy\'s dog%'`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE '%sandy''s dog%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE '%sandy_s dog%'
```

The underscore is a "single character" wildcard.